# How to let CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage work with Kanji and Emojis?

Tags: swift, core-text

This question is related to CoreText (available among Apple platforms). The langauge is `Swift 5.10`.

It seems that the `CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage()` doesn't return usable results if the given UniChar array contains kanji / emoji.

### My attempts:

Suppose that I utilize `CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage()` using the following Swift script.

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import CoreText
import Foundation

guard let osFont = CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage(
  .system, 14, "zh-Hant" as CFString
) else {
  print("CTFont initiation failed.")
  exit(1) // Abortion.
}

extension CTFont {
  func glyphs(for string: String) -> [CGGlyph]? {
    let arrUTF16 = Array(string.utf16)
    var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: 0, count: arrUTF16.count)
    let result = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(self, arrUTF16, &glyphs, arrUTF16.count)
    return result ? glyphs : nil
  }
}

let string = "這是草莓蛋糕。" // NOTE: Edit this line to try various parameters.
let unichars = Array(string.utf16)

var fetchedGlyphs: [CGGlyph]? = osFont.glyphs(for: string)
guard var fetchedGlyphs = fetchedGlyphs else {
  print("Screwed. I don't know why it only works with ASCII glyphs.")
  exit(1) // Abortion.
}
```

> Note that the CTFont can be replaced by `NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)` instead of the one I created above. CTFont and NSFont are toll-free bridgable in Swift 5.

### The problem in the case:

The `(CTFont instance).glyphs(for:)` returns nil if the given string parameter contains kanji and / or emoji characters. One may try with other kanji-only strings or emoji-only strings.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no single font that supports both Chinese characters and emojis.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. I forgot to state that the issue still exists even if the string contains only kanji or only emoji.

Comment: I'm not saying an emoji-only string would work with this code. You should use [`CTFontCreateForString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1509506-ctfontcreateforstring) to get a font that supports the characters in your string.

Comment: Thanks. It finally works with Emojis. Although there is an issue that unusable results are returnd from the zh-Hant OS UI font, it is outside of the scope of this question thread. Should I close this question or do anything else? I got too much penalties from asking low-rated questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`CTFontCreateForString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1509506-ctfontcreateforstring), or its corresponding `init`. This looks up the font in the font cascade list and finds a font that supports as many characters in the given string as possible.

```
let string = "你好"
let baseFont = CTFont(.system, size: 14)
let osFont = CTFont(font: baseFont, string: string as CFString, range: CFRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
if let fetchedGlyphs = osFont.glyphs(for: string) {
    print(fetchedGlyphs)
}
```